# How can I redirect to use the new context not the origin context with django?

Tags: python, django

I use a decorator to check whether the user is logged in, and redirect to the login page and remind the user. I want to use context parametric rendering template. How can I write the code?

```py
def check_login(func):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.session.get("unique_id"):
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            context = {'title': 'login', 'not_login': 1}
            return redirect(reverse('login'), context=context)
    return wrapper


# view.py
def login(request):
    context = {'title': 'login', 'not_login': 0}
    return render(request, 'login.html', context)
```

The code like this. If user get the login page, templates use `not_login=0`, if the request is from redirect, templates use `not_login=1`.

Comment: Why not `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPMA Because If the cookies is timeout and the page is still there, I need to remind the user login again.